# Ativar função em outra página após clicar em âncora

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Exemplo básico, ao clicar na `div1` da `Pagina1` abrir a `Pagina2` e alterar a cor de fundo, isso é possível?

**Pagina1.html**

```
<body>
<div>
<a href="Pagina2.html#div1"  class="">div1</a>
<a href="Pagina2.html#div2"  class="">div2</a>
</div>
</body>
```

**Pagina2.html**

```
<body>
<div id="div1"></div>//body background azul
<div id="div2"></div>//body background verde
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade `.hash` do objeto [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), para capturar/verificar se foi informado alguma âncora para a segunda página:

Utilize o script na `Pagina2`:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    alterarCor(hash);
}

function alterarCor(ancora) {
    if (ancora == "#div1") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    } else if (ancora == "#div2") {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas aqui vai:

**01.html:**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="02.html?div=1"  id="d1">Cor1</a>
        <a href="02.html?div=2"  id="d2">Cor2</a>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var url   = window.location.search.replace("?", ""); //pega url
    var itens = url.split("&"); //pega meus parâmetros (div=1 ou div=2)
    var valor = itens[0].slice(4); // retira 4 c. pois div= tem 4 caracteres
    if(valor == 1)
    {
        document.bgColor = "yellow";  // se for Cor 1 muda para amarelo
    }
    else if(valor == 2)
    {
        document.bgColor = "red";   // se for Cor 2 muda para vermelho
    }
</script>
```

**02.html:**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="01.html?div=1"  id="d1">Cor1</a>
        <a href="01.html?div=2"  id="d2">Cor2</a>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var url   = window.location.search.replace("?", ""); //pega url
    var itens = url.split("&"); //pega meus parâmetros (div=1 ou div=2)
    var valor = itens[0].slice(4); // retira 4 c. pois div= tem 4 caracteres
    if(valor == 1)
    {
        document.bgColor = "blue";  // se for Cor 1 muda para azul
    }
    else if(valor == 2)
    {
        document.bgColor = "green";  // se for Cor 2 muda para verde
    }
</script>
```

**Em uma mesma página:**

Fiz esse exemplo em uma mesma página, se clicar em tal link ele muda a cor:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="this.html?div=1"  id="d1">Cor1</a>
        <a href="this.html?div=2"  id="d2">Cor2</a>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var url   = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    var itens = url.split("&");
    var valor = itens[0].slice(4); // 5 pois nome= tem 5 caracteres
    if(valor == 1)
    {
        document.bgColor = "blue"; 
    }
    else if(valor == 2)
    {
        document.bgColor = "green"; 
    }
</script>
```