# Como faço para que ao clicar em um link eu ativo uma função JS em outra pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

quero que ao clicar no link da primeira pagina, ele vai para a segunda pagina e faz a função JS, que é mostrar só o que pertence ao esporte do link

ou seja quero clicar no link da primeira pagina e ir para a segunda e ser ativado o js na segunda pelo click da primeira pagina

pensei em alguma coisa com ancora mas nao achei solução

essa é a pagina 1

```
<div>
  <ul id="Menu1">
     <li class="Esporte"><a href="Pagina2.html"><p>Futebol</p></a></li>
     <li class="Esporte"><a href="Pagina2.html"><p>Basquete</p></a></li>
     <li class="Esporte"><a href="Pagina2.html"><p>Outros</p></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Pagina 2

```
<div class='Modalidade'>    <p class='Esporte1'>    Futebol </p></div>
<div class='Modalidade'>    <p class='Esporte1'>    Basquete    </p></div>
<div class='Modalidade'>    <p class='Esporte1'>    Outros  </p></div>
```

JS

```
 $('#Menu1 .Esporte').click(function(){
    var Esportes = $(this).text();
    $('.Modalidade').hide();
    $('.Modalidade .Esporte1:contains(' + Esportes + ')').parent().show();
 });
```

Comment: @Ney você já fez essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110435/30045) e você resolver o problema acima utilizando ela mesma!

Answer (score 0):

@Ney, pelo o JS vejo que você esta escondendo uma div e mostrando outra. A intenção e essa ou é chamar outra pagina html?
Essas informações que você deseja mostrar que depende do esporte que ele clicar na lista vai vir do banco correto?
Antes do `parent().show()` faça a requisição:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post', //Tipo de envio, GET, POST....
  data: 'esporte=Esporte', // envio da variavel Esporte com o texto (acho mais interessante você passar um valor que seria uma chave primaria mais vai depender do seu banco de dados
  url:'dados.php', // Url do arquivo que vai chamar
  success: function(retorno){
      $('.Modalidade .Esporte1:contains(' + Esportes + ')').parent().show();
  }
   })
```

Revi o seu código o que você deseja é mudar para a pagina2.html e mostrar apenas o que estiver na div do esporte que a pessoa clicou.
Você pode ainda fazer da maneira que achei aqui no StackOverflow.
[Link do Stack sobre o mesmo assunto.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75557/passando-valores-js-para-outra-pagina-html)

Comment: o que eu quero é, clicou no link da pagina 1 futebol, abre a pagina 2 e mostra só o futebol

Comment: Acredito que essas 3 maneiras existentes da para fazer o que deseja.
Editei o comentário que fiz e acrescentei uma outra pagina do Stack que tem 2 maneiras que da para fazer o que você deseja.